# get current and total slide with mupltiple sliders

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js to have mulplte horizontal sliders. Basically you can scroll veirtaclly to each slider then slide horizontal within each section. What I want to do is display the current slide/total slides for each section. The issue I am having is since they all have the same class it is getting the total for the whole page opposed to total for each section and also the current slide wont change since its getting the "active" class from all the slides.

HTML

```
<div class="section" id="section1" >

            <div class="slide" id="golf1"></div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide2"></div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide3"></div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide4"></div>

            <div class="slideContent">
                <div class="num"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="section" id="section2">

            <div class="slide" id="skills1"></div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide2"></div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide3"></div>
            <div class="slide" id="slide4"></div>

            <div class="slideContent">

                <div class="num"></div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

JS

```
  var totalItems = $('.slide').length;
            var currentIndex = $('.slide.active').index() + 1;
            $('.num').html(''+currentIndex+'/'+totalItems+'');
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: all the slide id's???

Comment: @Packy Yes, ALL id attributes in the DOM must be unique.

Comment: Still not sure how that will allow the total slides be constrained to getting total slides for each section not the whole page

Comment: @Packy see my answer below.  It won't directly help you get the total/current slides but it will help clean up your DOM and avoid future problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle for you, and the functioning jquery

I made a pretty big edit to my answer to include functionality to run on an event, for this purpose I just used 'click' on a section, obviously you'll want to change this for your events.  I also added an alert of the current slide index so you could see it's working.

To use, just call the slideCounts() function with the index (starting with 0) of the section for which you want to update the counter.  The each loop adds the counters on document ready.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/168xofn3/4/

jQuery - you want to loop through all the sections, count the slides in the section, then get the active slide.  Then output active slide / total slides for each section.

```
$('.section').each(function(i){
    slideCounts(i);
});

$('.section').on('click',function(){
    var i = $(this).index();
    slideCounts(i);
});


function slideCounts(i){
    var elm = $('.section').eq(i);
    var total = elm.find('.slide').length;
    var current = elm.find('.active').index();
    current++;
    elm.find('.num').html(''+current+'/'+total+'');
    alert(current);  //remove this alert

}
```

I've also changed your markup a bit for the example to work

```
<div class="section" id="section1" >
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide active"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>

    <div class="slideContent">
        <div class="num"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section" id="section2" >
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide active"></div>

    <div class="slideContent">
        <div class="num"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section" id="section3" >
    <div class="slide active"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>

    <div class="slideContent">
        <div class="num"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run this function for each section then, not for the whole page.
Kinda like so:

```
$('.section').each(function(){
    var section = $(this),
        sectionSlides = section.find('.slide'),
        totalItems = sectionSlides.length,
        currentIndex = sectionSlides.filter('.active').index() + 1,
        numContainer = section.find('.num'); //assuming you have numContainers in every section

    numContainer.html(currentIndex + '/' + totalItems);
});
```

**Edit:**
If you want to run this function multiple times (to update the current active index in each section on slide change). Run this function each time the slides change. The code might look like this then:

```
var sections = $('.section');

updateCurrentIndex(); //on document.ready and on each slidechange

function updateCurrentIndex(){
    sections.each(function(){
        var section = $(this),
            sectionSlides = section.find('.slide'),
            totalItems = sectionSlides.length,
            currentIndex = sectionSlides.filter('.active').index() + 1,
            numContainer = section.find('.num'); //assuming you have numContainers in every section

        numContainer.html(currentIndex + '/' + totalItems);
    });
}
```

Note however that you may want to move several parts away from this function (things like the total items number, since it's not changed and other things), to put it simply - this function is more of a proff of concept, it needs a bit of refactoring for it to be ready for production )) sorry

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was a way to not have so many functions but I guess not. This is getting the slide total now fine but not updating the current slide (always says 1/4)

Comment: Not sure why... probably the active slide is the first? ) I checked my code against @guid's fiddle. works good too http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/168xofn3/3/

Comment: or do you want the number of the current slide to update on slide change?

Comment: I was looking to have the current slide update on slide change

Comment: Anyone solved this? I'm really interested!
I tried this jsfiddle.net/skip405/168xofn3/3 and it works fine, the only thing is that it does not update the number ever slide.